# Deployed to Tomcat 7 OK but cannot access application

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins, tomcat7

I have a CI-deployed Java Wicket application using Jenkins -> Tomcat 7 on a server.  All seems fine up until the point I try to access the application through a browser (via the listing of the deployed application in the manager app).  Then I get a 404 error.  In the logs, I can see from the tomcat7-stdout-.log that the application starts up fine - the spring beans I set up are outputting init debug statements from my code, so it looks ready to go with no errors.

My dev machine is 32-bit win7.  The server is 64-bit Win Server 2008 R2

Thinking it might have been the way Jenkins builds the war file, or an incompatibility between 32/64-bit versions, I installed Tomcat 7 locally so it's all on the same machine, and I get the same result when I deploy from the manager application.

- When I shut down tomcat and try to access localhost:8080, nothing appears so there is no other apps competing for that port that I can see
- Creating a META-INF/context.xml with `<Context path="/system4" />` inside doesn't affect the deployment either (ie it still says it's at the path specified by the war name).
- I followed the instructions [here](http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/tomcat-6-infamous-severe-error-listenerstart-message-how-to-debug-this-error/) to remove some error listenerStart issues, but the log file created is empty
- Running locally via mvn jetty:run starts the app with no problems.  I can then navigate to the app successfully on localhost:8080
- There are no errors in the log files.  Below is the total output from each file from a (local) deployment.

localhost..log:

```
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@46128d')
```

localhost_access_log.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - tomcatgui [01/Jul/2013:11:48:11 +0100] "GET /manager/html/list?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=DBBBE417970CCAAB039E98C236CB177A HTTP/1.1" 200 15822
127.0.0.1 - tomcatgui [01/Jul/2013:11:48:11 +0100] "GET /manager/images/asf-logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - tomcatgui [01/Jul/2013:11:48:11 +0100] "GET /manager/images/tomcat.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - tomcatgui [01/Jul/2013:11:48:16 +0100] "GET /manager/html/list?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=634AA4131BBA0B7368023C32CD653FC8 HTTP/1.1" 200 15822
127.0.0.1 - tomcatgui [01/Jul/2013:11:48:34 +0100] "POST /manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=AA80212A2557D18475CB621F165BD24E HTTP/1.1" 200 17716
```

host-manager..log (empty)

catalina..log:

```
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.4.6.
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013)
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1152 ms
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\docs
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\examples
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\host-manager
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\manager
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\ROOT
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 440 ms
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\system4-ui-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

servlet-examples..log (the one suggested in the link) (empty - the logging level is set to ALL)

manager..log:

```
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

Output from the tomcat window:

```
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.4
.6.
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], ra
ndom [true].
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializ
eSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013)
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1152 ms
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\docs
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\exampl
es
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\host-m
anager
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\manage
r
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\ROOT
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 01, 2013 11:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 440 ms
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\webapps\system4-
ui-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
FINE: Sending application start events
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
FINE: Starting filters
Jul 01, 2013 11:48:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
FINE:  Starting filter 'wicket.system4-ui'
INFO  - WebXmlFile                 - web.xml: url mapping found for filter with
name wicket.system4-ui: [/*]
INFO  - Application                - [wicket.system4-ui] init: Wicket core libra
ry initializer
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListe
nerInterface name=IBehaviorListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wick
et.behavior.IBehaviorListener.onRequest()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListe
nerInterface name=IFormSubmitListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wi
cket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener.onFormSubmitted()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListe
nerInterface name=ILinkListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.m
arkup.html.link.ILinkListener.onLinkClicked()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListe
nerInterface name=IOnChangeListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wick
et.markup.html.form.IOnChangeListener.onSelectionChanged()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListe
nerInterface name=IRedirectListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wick
et.IRedirectListener.onRedirect()]
INFO  - RequestListenerInterface   - registered listener interface [RequestListe
nerInterface name=IResourceListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wick
et.IResourceListener.onResourceRequested()]
INFO  - Application                - [wicket.system4-ui] init: Wicket extensions
 initializer
INFO  - sPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.supp
ort.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@19b35e1: startup date [Mon Jul 01 11:48:32 BS
T 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader    - Loading XML bean definitions from class pat
h resource [META-INF/applicationContext-data.xml]
INFO  - sPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation fou
nd and supported for component scanning
INFO  - nnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation fo
und and supported for autowiring
INFO  - sPathXmlApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Hi
bernateJpaVendorAdapter#5d2d9b' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendo
r.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPo
stProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  - sPathXmlApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.instrument.classl
oading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver#f003c0' of type [class org.springframework.
instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver] is not eligible for getti
ng processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxy
ing)
INFO  - erEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory
 for persistence unit 'com.sw.system4.core.persistence'
INFO  - Version                    - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
{4.0.1.Final}
INFO  - Version                    - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.0.Final}
INFO  - Environment                - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO  - Environment                - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassi
st
INFO  - Ejb3Configuration          - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [

        name: com.sw.system4.core.persistence
        ...]
INFO  - agerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connect
ion pool (not for production use!)
INFO  - agerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size:
20
INFO  - agerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
INFO  - agerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Dri
ver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/system4_live]
INFO  - agerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=sys
tem4_user, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
INFO  - Dialect                    - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dia
lect.MySQL5Dialect
INFO  - ransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibern
ate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
INFO  - ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  - SchemaUpdate               - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
INFO  - SchemaUpdate               - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
INFO  - SchemaUpdate               - HHH000396: Updating schema
INFO  - TableMetadata              - HHH000261: Table found: system4_live.user
INFO  - TableMetadata              - HHH000037: Columns: [id, enabled, username,
 preferences_id, lastlogin, lastname, firstname, password, changepasswordrequire
d]
INFO  - TableMetadata              - HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk285feb559233ea]

INFO  - TableMetadata              - HHH000126: Indexes: [primary, fk285feb55923
3ea]
INFO  - TableMetadata              - HHH000261: Table found: system4_live.userpr
eferences
INFO  - TableMetadata              - HHH000037: Columns: [id]
INFO  - TableMetadata              - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
INFO  - TableMetadata              - HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
INFO  - SchemaUpdate               - HHH000232: Schema update complete
INFO  - sPathXmlApplicationContext - Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [class
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligi
ble for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible f
or auto-proxying)
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springf
ramework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@66d804: defining beans
 [entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.Pe
rsistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAu
toProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionA
ttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionIntercep
tor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,persiste
nceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.inte
rnalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.inte
rnalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internal
RequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommo
nAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceA
nnotationProcessor,userJpaDAO,user-service,encryption-service,org.springframewor
k.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root
 of factory hierarchy
INFO  - MD5EncryptionStrategy      - EncryptionStrategy: Using MD5 for encryptio
n
INFO  - WebApplication             - [wicket.system4-ui] Started Wicket version
6.8.0 in DEVELOPMENT mode
********************************************************************
*** WARNING: Wicket is running in DEVELOPMENT mode.              ***
***                               ^^^^^^^^^^^                    ***
*** Do NOT deploy to your live server(s) without changing this.  ***
*** See Application#getConfigurationType() for more information. ***
********************************************************************
```

If I click on the link for the app in the tomcat manager application, I get:

```
type Status report

message /system4%2Dui%2D0.0.1%2DSNAPSHOT/

description The requested resource is not available.
```

and this appears in localhost-access..log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jul/2013:11:54:38 +0100] "GET /system4%2Dui%2D0.0.1%2DSNAPSHOT/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1015
```

Please can anyone help?

Comment: It suggests to me that you just have the wrong URL to access the app.

Comment: I thought that might have been it, but how do I find out the correct URL?  I've been using the link from the tomcat manager gui - list applications tab, so I would have thought that was the right one to use.

Comment: I hope you're packaging your app as a WAR file and adding that to the /webapps directory and not piling it all into the /ROOT directory.  None of your stuff belongs there.  If you are, then it's just http://localhost:8080/<war-file-name>/index.html

Comment: no the war file is being packaged correctly and being placed in webapps.  Tomcat then detects and extracts the file correctly and gives the expected output above.

Comment: So the URL that I gave, assuming you have an index.html, doesn't work?

Comment: no that url doesnt work, with or without index.html.  Ive fixed it (see below) but no idea why it's wrong

Comment: If you want it to run under context root / (the ROOT context root), here's how I did it. http://macgyverdev.blogspot.se/2014/02/how-to-change-context-root-to-in-tomcat.html. It works fine with my Jenkins -> Tomcat 7 deploy plugin.

Answer (score 8):

OK, well this is strange.

It was all down to the name of the WAR file, and thus the URL of the site.  I renamed the war file to just system4.war, and tried to deploy that, and I could navigate to the URL just fine.

I say it's strange, because I ran the wicket quickstart project some months ago on the very same server, and the war file was named very similarly (ie wickettestproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war) and this worked ok, although after redeploying this project now, that no longer works either.

I'm at a loss as to why, because AFAIK dots and dashes are ok in a URL - maybe it's a tomcat quirk or something.

To fix the problem:

In the pom.xml I use to generate the WAR, I've included this line under the build tags:

```
<finalName>system4</finalName>
```

Now the war is renamed, it's built and deployed under system4.war, and accessed via `<server>:<port>/system4`